# Reference Request-Free Algebraic Structure

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, universal-algebra

I am looking for a reference that treats free algebraic structures, such as free groups, free modules and free algebras together. (I would also not mind, and would prefer, if it treats the categorical part of it in the categorical setting.) Thanks for reading this post!

Comment: Before asking any question, please check whether Wikipedia does not answer it immediately. For your question, did you look at [Free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I am not looking for the definition, but for a comprehensive source (that means in a text format).

Answer (score 2):

What about the article [Free Structures](http://www.heldermann.de/R&E/RAE18/ctw15.pdf) by Reiterman and Trnkova in "Category Theory at Work".

Answer (score 2):

I quite like the approach in Bergman "An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions". It does a good job of balancing the algebra and the category theory.